# bootstrap 3 button and label not bottom aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

The label and button are not vertical aligned. The button floats up.  I've searched and tried those solutions but they did not work.  Head thoroughly banged against wall.

Here's the fiddle.  http://www.bootply.com/5877LkksdX

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-xs-2  ">
        <h3><label class="label label-primary">
                Student Information</label></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 ">
       <input id="Button3" type="button" value="Add Student" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what were those solutions that you say you tried... so we don't have to guess?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/K6FsGNHwZI i hope this sweets your need

Comment: @ZeRuBuES - Thanks I'm using your solution.  I works even though you spelled absolute wrong. haha  I did have to change the margin to 12.  Please add it as a question so I can mark it correct.

Comment: @WilliamPrice - You are right, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

The "Student Information" text is wrapped in an `H3` tag which has `margin-top: 20px;` and `margin-bottom: 10px;`  I suggest you take it out of the H3 and create a custom CSS class for it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mytitle">
  <label class="label label-primary">Student Information</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mytitle {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I played around with this but there were a lot of other things that needed to get adjusted as well.  Thanks

Comment: You should probably re-phrase your original question to better clarify what you are asking for. Right now you only mention that you want the buttons aligned. If you need help for other items you should have asked that from the get go.

Comment: Hey @crazymatt, Thanks for you help but what I meant was that there is more than just those 5 CSS properties to change to get it to match Bootstrap not more to my question.